# The binomial theorem and composite functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A question begins with this context (I'm paraphrasing a bit):

(1) Under the context of function composition, raising a function to a power means we compose, for example, $f^2 = fof$, $(fog)^2 = fogofog$, and so on

(2) Function composition is not commutative, $fog(x)$ is not always $gof(x)$

Then the Q: Will the binomial expansion theorem work with function composition, why or why not? (so we can't just contradict by a numerical case, but we can do a contradiction in the quadratic case using general variables)

The answer to the question considers $(fog+gof)^2$, and sees that it's equal to $(fog)(fog)+(fog)(gof)+(gof)(fog)+(gof)(gof)$, by the $distr. prop.$ which can easily be motivated

If the $B.th.$ does work, it should be simplified down to $(fog)^2 + 2(fog)(gof) + (gof)^2$

Now here's the confusion:

The answer says that the $B.th.$ does not work because if $fog = a$ and $gof = b$, then $(fog)(gof) = ab$ and $(gof)(fog) = ba$, since ab is not equal to $ba$, it can't just be $2ab$

If you just have $fog(x)$ and $gof(x)$ as two things that multiply to each other in parenthesis as shown in the $FOILED$ out form, then can't we just simply factor it to $2ab$, it seems completely fine algebraically?

Now, if we had our thing with the context that was going on with how $(fog)^2 = fogofog$, I would understand, but what doesn't make sense (the $"right?"$'s are not me be being certain and asking for agreement, they are questions):

```
  isn't just that we use the exponent as notation, surely it isn't algebraic 
  that $(fog(x))^2 = 
  fogofog(x)$, right?

  So then if we multiply using $FOIL$, we can just rewrite $ab + ba = 2ab$, 
  because if just doing this 
  algebraic multiplication, it is commutative, right?

  It seems that we don't have to worry about whether the $b.th.$ uses 
  exponents as function 
  composition, because the answer given to this question says that $ab + ba$ 
  is 
  not $2ab$, so we should 
  be good enough by just clearing that up
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Although composition looks like multiplication, it is not.

Comment: I think with $ab$ it's meant as $a\circ b$ and $b\circ a$ not $a\cdot b$ and $b\cdot a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to (1) we consider *powers* of functions as *compositions*. In this problem we do not have any multiplication of functions but only addition and composition of functions. We define
\begin{align*}
f^2&:= f\circ f\tag{1.1}
\end{align*}
and squaring a sum of functions in this context means *composition* of a sum of functions.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(f+g)^2}&=(f+g)\color{blue}{\circ}(f+g)\tag{2.1}\\
> &=\left(f\circ(f+g)\right) + \left(g\circ(f+g)\right)\tag{2.2}\\
> &=f\circ f+f\circ g + g\circ f + g\circ f\tag{2.3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=f^2+f\circ g + g\circ f +g^2}\tag{2.4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2.1) we use when squaring $(f+g)$ the *composition* of functions as in (1.1).
- In (2.2) we apply the distributive law, noting that *composition* of function takes precedence over *addition* of functions.
- In (2.3) we use the distributive law again.
- In (2.4) we use the power notation for compositions of $f$ and $g$ with itself.

> Substituting $f$ with $f\circ g$ and $g$ with $g\circ f$ in (2.1) we obtain the binomial expansion of a composition of functions.
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{(\left(f\circ g\right)+\left(g\circ f\right) )^2}\\
> &\quad=(\left(f\circ g\right)+\left(g\circ f\right) )\color{blue}{\circ}(\left(f\circ g\right)+\left(g\circ f\right) )\\
> &\quad=\left(f\circ g\right)\circ(\left(f\circ g\right)+\left(g\circ f\right))\\
> &\qquad\qquad+ \left(g\circ f\right)\circ(\left(f\circ g\right)+\left(g\circ f\right))\\
> &\quad=\left(f\circ g\right)\circ \left(f\circ g\right)+\left(f\circ g\right)\circ \left(g\circ f\right)\\
> &\quad\qquad+ \left(g\circ f\right) \circ \left(f\circ g\right) + \left(g\circ f\right) \circ \left(g\circ f\right) \\
> &\quad=\left(f\circ g\right)^2+\left(f\circ g\right)\circ \left(g\circ f\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad  + \left(g\circ f\right) \circ \left(f\circ g\right) +\left(g\circ f\right) ^2\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{\quad=\left(f\circ g\right)^2+f\circ g^2\circ f  + g\circ f^2\circ g+\left(g\circ f\right)^2}\tag{3.1}
> \end{align*}

In (3.1) we use the associativity of the composition of functions. We observe that since *composition* of functions is not commutative, i.e. we do not have in general $f\circ g=g\circ f$, the binomial expansion theorem $(a+b)^2=a^2+\color{blue}{2}ab+b^2$ does not hold in general for function compositions.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about it like this $(f\circ g)(x)\cdot (g\circ f)(x)= f(g(x))\cdot g(f(x))=g(f(x))\cdot f(g(x))=(g\circ f)(x)\cdot (f\circ g)(x)$\

In essence, it is true that $(f\circ g)(x)\neq (g\circ f)(x)$ but functions are still commutative. In fact, $fg=gf$

Comment: does that mean that $(fog(x)+gof(x))^2 = ... + 2(fog(x))(gof(x)) + ... $

Comment: Yes, you can just multiply it out as $(a+b)^n$. But always be cautious with the context you work this out.

Comment: sorry to pile on requests for confirmation, I've just been stuck on this for a long time and wanted to be sure, does that mean that the b.th. expansion does work for function composition

Comment: Yes, it works. Don't worry a lot about it. You can ask any questions you have about math here